# Installing GAP( group algorithm programming) for mackbook Air M1

Tags: macos, install, apple-silicon

I am using MacBook Air M1. I downloaded GAP from https://www.gap-system.org/ the file gap-4.12.2.tar.gz . In download, I double-click it and there is a folder with the name gap-4.12.2 . Now I cannot install it as I am new in computer knowledge. Please help me step by step process to install and run GAP. Thank You .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unfamiliar with installing/compiling Unix binaries on macOS, you can use Homebrew (a package manager) for this.

- Install Homebrew by following the instructions on https://brew.sh
- Run `brew install gap-system/gap/gap` in Terminal to install GAP.

Comment: curl: (28) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 after 75315 ms: Operation timed out------------ this is showing

Comment: this problem is solved by DNS8.8.8.8

Comment: Now brew install gap-system/gap/gap is problem

Comment: @neelkanth We can't see the output on your screen, so unless you share that with us, we can't help you.

Comment: I think now it is solved after calling the gap on the terminal it is as below

Comment: GAP 4.12.2 of 2022-12-18
 │  GAP  │   https://www.gap-system.org
 └───────┘   Architecture: aarch64-apple-darwin21-default64-kv8
 Configuration:  gmp 6.2.1, GASMAN, readline
 Loading the library and packages ...
 Packages:   AClib 1.3.2, Alnuth 3.2.1, AtlasRep 2.1.6, AutPGrp 1.11, 
             ,

Comment: Browse 1.8.19, CaratInterface 2.3.4, CRISP 1.4.6, Cryst 4.1.25, 
             CrystCat 1.1.10, CTblLib 1.3.4, curlInterface 2.3.1, 
             FactInt 1.6.3, FGA 1.4.0, Forms 1.2.9, GAPDoc 1.6.6, genss 1.6.8, 
             IO 4.8.0, IRREDSOL 1.4.4, LAGUNA 3.9.5, orb 4.9.0, 
             Polenta 1.3.10, Polycyclic 2.16, PrimGrp 3.4.3, RadiRoot 2.9, 
             recog 1.4.2, ResClasses 4.7.3, SmallGrp 1.5.1, Sophus 1.27, 
             SpinSym 1.5.2, TomLib 1.2.9, TransGrp 3.6.3, utils 0.81
 Try '??help' for help. See also '?copyright', '?cite' and '?authors'
gap>

Comment: Now it is complete sir? or is anything remaining?  and the last two questions in the terminal running gap is always method? Sir both methods give game GAP or there is any difference between these?

Comment: @neelkanth I don‘t known the software at all.

Answer (score 0):

The installation instructions for macOS are mentioned on the linked page, under the section titled **The Basic Steps of a GAP Installation**:

> - https://www.gap-system.org/Download/index.html
> - Verify that [all required tools](https://www.gap-system.org/Download/tools.html) are installed.
> - Choose your preferred archive format and [download](https://www.gap-system.org/Releases/4.12.2.html) the corresponding archive.
> - Unpack the archive.
> - On UNIX, Linux or macOS: compile the GAP core system by running `./configure; make` in the unpacked directory.
> - On UNIX, Linux or macOS: change to the pkg subdirectory and call `../bin/BuildPackages.sh` to run the script which will build most of
>   the packages that require compilation (provided sufficiently many
>   libraries, headers and tools are available). If something doesn't work
>   on your system, please refer to the README file provided with the
>   corresponding package.
> - On Windows: no compilation is needed, since compiled executables for GAP and some packages are already provided by the `.exe` installer.
> - Adjust some links/scripts/icons etc., depending on your system, to make the new version of GAP available to the users of your machine.
> - Optional: run a few tests.

Alternatively, you can install via Homebrew. This is a preferred approach if you do not wish to perform compilation yourself.

- https://github.com/gap-system/homebrew-gap

Do note however that the linked tap is unofficial and unmaintained.

Comment: Actually these are given on GAP site but I am unable to apply these

Comment: @neelkanth please edit your question to be more specific about the things which don‘t work for you.

Comment: @nohillside please tell me how to apply this step?     On UNIX, Linux or macOS: compile the GAP core system by running ./configure; make in the unpacked directory.

Comment: @Nimesh Neema How to apply this step On UNIX, Linux or macOS: compile the GAP core system by running ./configure; make in the unpacked directory. Thank you.

Comment: @neelkanth see 2nd answer for an easier way.